# How to see from the graph if a function $f(x)$ is $O(\alpha^x)$ or $O(x^{n})$

Tags: calculus

Often in applied mathematics it is useful to determine if some function $f(x)$ grows as order $O(x^{n})$ and/or $O(\alpha^x)$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $x\geq 0$ just by studying its graph, i.e. without taking its logarithm.

What is the easiest way to determine its order just from its graph $(x, f(x))$? At first glance they look to similar to discriminate.

Comment: When you say "just by studying its graph" do you mean just by looking at the visual representation of the graph, or something else? If you mean looking that the graph, then this is impossible, since you can only see finite length pieces of the domain and range and so could not make any definite conclusions: a function may look to be of a certain order on some piece of its domain, but that doesn't tell you anything about the function's behavior on its infinite domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what happens 
when you go from
$x$ to $2x$ to $3x$ to $4x$.

If it is $x^n$,
the ratio of
$\dfrac{f(kx)}{f(x)}$
would be
$k^n$,
so 
the ratios would be
$2^n, 3^n, 4^n$,
so the third is the square of the first.

if it is $a^n$,
the ratio would be
$a^{(k-1)x}$,
so the ratios would be
$a^x, a^{2x}, a^{3x}$,
and the second is 
the square of the first.